# Variable Custom View and Android Studio Design/Layout Editor

Tags: android, android-custom-view

There is a simple `Custom_TextView`. This is a regular `TextView` with a border, for example.

There is a `Custom_TextBar`, of the following design: `Custom_TextView + Custom_TextView + ...`

In other words, these are several `Custom_TextViews`, one after another, the text is taken from the variable length list. The list is not known in advance.

> Custom_TextBar = Custom_TextView + Custom_TextView + …

A list with text (and font size, margins) is sent to the `Custom_TextBar`, which draws several `Custom_TextView`.

It all works.

**Question**.

How to force Android Studio Design / Layout Editor to display, for example, a kind of empty rectangle to make the design of the other components of the fragment?

For example, suppose a list has 3 identical elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not for the first time I notice that by asking a question on SO I find the answer, this is not on purpose;)

So, the solution:

```
// in Custom_TextBar

public TextBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
}

public void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    // ... everything is as usual
    // ...
    if (textDataList == null) {
        stub();
    }
}

private void stub() {
    // ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        View textView = new TextRectangle(getContext(), 
           new TextRectangleData("test" + i), textSize, margins, ...);
        // ...
    }
}
```